# Having trouble relating Core Data to HTML to printing

Tags: html, objective-c, core-data, printing, nsattributedstring

There doesn't seem to be a huge amount that describes how I could print off my core data information. I have seen a couple of articles or posts advocating using NSAttributedString, NSTextView, or the frameworks WebKit and AppKit.

I'm just having trouble relating all the concepts. I've converted my core data into what I believe is HTML-style string in an NSAttributedString. What can I do with that? I've tried the NSTextView function "-insertText", so that I could use the "-print" function, however my program crashes when I attempt to do so, giving me this error:

```
 -[__NSTaggedDate insertText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Any help would be appreciated. In my program I would like to be able to print multiple tables, as well as invoice-styled receipts.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I'm trying to take all the entries in my table and print them to a nice looking report. I haven't found a clear-cut answer yet. Although it sounds like the general consensus is to dump core data to html and then print the webpage to .pdf. What method did you use to dump your core data entries to html?